# How to add a tooltip on Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, tooltip

Did anyone understand how to show a small tooltip in ionic?

I think that there must exists something like a "title" attribute, but i can't find it...

I tried to add a [title]="" in my ion-inputs, ion-items, but nothing showsup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a module that can be included in your project. Try using this
[ionic-tooltips](https://github.com/zyra/ionic-tooltips)

Comment: Jazib, thanks for the response. Yes, I tried, but that module seems to work only for buttons and i need it for inputs

Comment: Hi Mitias, look at this solution given in the same issue reported to the repo. see if this helps.
 https://github.com/zyra/ionic-tooltips/issues/40#issuecomment-414680860

Comment: it's been a while, but this works for me:

https://www.itechinsiders.com/2019/02/how-to-show-tooltip-in-ionic3-and-ionic4/

Answer (score 6):

Checkout [ionic4-tooltips](https://GitHub.com/jrquick17/ionic4-tooltips). It is actively maintained.